# Why does DoubleClick's floodlight tag cast a variable to a String and the to a number again?

Tags: javascript, google-floodlight

The JS implementation of DoubleClick's floodlight tag looks something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="https://123.fls.doubleclick.net/(snip);ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Interestingly, to get the random impression ID (the parameter `ord`), the var `axel` is fist coerced into a string, then back into a Number `a` and lastly back into a string when the iframe's `src` attribute is being constructed.
Why is this done in this way? What's the difference to just using

```js
var a = Math.random() * 10000000000000 + "";
```

Comment: Even this will be work `var a = Math.random() * 10000000000000;` because  it will be converted to string when you build parameter for `document.write`

Comment: You're absolutely correct. One could argue that this single coercion helps in being explicit what the variable is being used for later.

Comment: They actually coerce the random number into a string, then into a number (via multiplication), then back into a string. It goes: NUM > STR > NUM > STR. Bizarre, right? It would be nice to know the reasoning...